# CPQ tool -Product rule

Tags: product, cpq

I have created a product rule successfully. Now I want to append a condition that of date that whenever the created date > some range, then only the product rule (Validation) should fire.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use date format in product rule follow the below format

> Created Date > YYYY-MM-DD